# Android studio can't compile app with assets folder

Tags: android, android-studio, android-assets

I want to use custom font in my application and i did everything in the right way, but when i build the project and run it it's `force stop` because it can't found `assets` folder!

That's the code from `MainActivity`:

```
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wlcText);
    tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "en_font.ttf");
    tv.setTypeface(tf);
```

this is the exception trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Font asset not found en_font.ttf
        at android.graphics.Typeface.createFromAsset(Typeface.java:198)
```

I have  `assets` folder in the right path like that [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeMXe.png)

Also i tried to browse my apk after compilation and i didn't found the assets folder in it like that [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZ7Kf.png)!

That's means Android studio can't see the folders in the project structure!

P.S. i tried a lot of questions here and nothing worked with me!

**EDIT**

That's the `build.gradle` with sourceSets:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mEmoZz.qrgen"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That seems odd. Do you have a `sourcesets` closure in that module's `build.gradle` file? If yes, edit your question and post that file.

Comment: Is your font file inside the assets folder itself or inside the fonts folder of the assets folder?

Comment: @BidhanA Inside the assets folder itself, also i try to put it in `/assets/fonts/` and the same exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Please rebuild your project it works.

Step - 

Open android studio -> Select Build option -> select rebuild option.
```